# FLStudio: Select notes in all channels

Tags: midi, fl-studio

Can I select notes in a few channels and move this in FLStudio?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. I've edited out your second sentence since we don't do software recommendationson this site.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can! shift+click on all the channel selectors that you want to copy (they will light up with a green border when selected). You can also double-click on one of the channel select buttons and it will select (highlight) all of them.

To copy the midi in each channel selected press ctr+c

To paste the midi into a different pattern, press ctr+v.